# Remove unknown icon appeared on home screen after mounting SD card

Tags: home-screen, app-icons

How to remove this icon from home screen of Xperia M2 Dual?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: THIS ICON APPEARED AFTER MOUNTING THE SD CARD]

Comment: May I ask what use it is to move your apps to SD card, and then remove that card? And for your question: which Icon do you want to remove? There is none labeled "this" :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have unmounted the SD card once. Behaviour might change on the implementation of launcher app, basically it should be solved by re-mounting the SD card. The icon with the mark is installed on the SD card.

Settings > Storage > SD Card > [Mount / Unmount]

Comment: Readers: Do a reboot if re-mount is not working.